# Using Gravital discord chatbot and getting "TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'" error

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to start this "Gravitar" discord ML chatbot, however every time I attempt to run my main.py I get this error. The main.py works fine, but when it refers to bot.py it starts to have some issues. I have tried several solutions to update what I believe to be outdated code (?) but I'm getting stuck.

```
  File "D:\Gravital-master\Bot\bot.py", line 19, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

This is the code it's referring to.

```
import random
import datetime
import discord
from .ai import ChatAI
from discord.ext import commands

class ChatBot(discord.Client):
    """ChatBot handles discord communication. This class runs its own thread that
    persistently watches for new messages, then acts on them when the bots username
    is mentioned. It will use the ChatAI class to generate messages then send them
    back to the configured server channel.

    ChatBot inherits the discord.Client class from discord.py
    """
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.',intents=intents)
    def __init__(self, maxlines) -> None:
        self.model_name = "355M"  # Overwrite with set_model_name()
        super().__init__()
        self.maxlines = maxlines  #see comment on main.py line 33

    async def on_ready(self) -> None:
        """ Initializes the GPT2 AI on bot startup """
        print("Logged on as", self.user)
        print(self.user.id)
        self.chat_ai = ChatAI(self.maxlines)  # Ready the GPT2 AI generator

    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message) -> None:
        """ Handle new messages sent to the server channels this bot is watching """
        if message.author == self.user:
            # Skip any messages sent by ourselves so that we don't get stuck in any loops
            return

        # Check to see if bot has been mentioned
        has_mentioned = False
        for mention in message.mentions:
            if str(mention) == self.user.name+"#"+self.user.discriminator:
                has_mentioned = True
                break

        # Only respond randomly (or when mentioned), not to every message
        if random.random() > float(self.response_chance) and has_mentioned == False:
            return

        async with message.channel.typing():
            # Get last n messages, save them to a string to be used as prefix
            context = ""
            # TODO: make limit parameter # configurable through command line args
            history = await message.channel.history(limit=9).flatten()
            history.reverse()  # put in right order
            for msg in history:
                # "context" now becomes a big string containing the content only of the last n messages, line-by-line
                context += msg.content + "\n"
            # probably-stupid way of making every line but the last have a newline after it
            context = context.rstrip(context[-1])
            
            # Print status to console
            print("----------Bot Triggered at {0:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}----------".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
            print("-----Context for message:")
            print(context)
            print("-----")

            # Process input and generate output
            processed_input = self.process_input(context)
            response = ""
            response = self.chat_ai.get_bot_response(processed_input)
            print("----Response Given:")
            print(response)
            print("----")

            await message.channel.send(response)# sends the response

    def process_input(self, message: str) -> str:
        """ Process the input message """
        processed_input = message
        # Remove bot's @s from input
        return processed_input.replace(("<@!" + str(self.user.id) + ">"), "")

    def set_response_chance(self, response_chance: float) -> None:
        """ Set the response rate """
        self.response_chance = response_chance

    def set_model_name(self, model_name: str = "355M") -> None:
        """ Set the GPT2 model name """
        self.model_name = model_name
```

I tried following examples from other peoples code but I'm afraid I still don't exactly understand what's wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
from Bot.bot import ChatBot
from Bot.ai import ChatAI


def main():
    """Main function"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Amalgam")
    parser.add_argument("--token", dest="MTA3MjMyNDc3OTgyODMxODIyOA.GKZNRE.1Wjpz1KPDzN6HohbaptBmYux-wzdU10u6DRKVM",
                        help="Your discord bot's token. Required for launching the bot in non-test mode!")
    parser.add_argument("--response_chance",
                        dest="response_chance",
                        default=1,
                        help="How likely the bot is to respond to a message in which it is not pinged. For example: give 0.25 for a 25%% chance, give 0 for no random responses. Defaults to 0.")
    parser.add_argument("--test", dest="test", action="store_true",
                        help="Test model by talking to the AI right in the terminal.")
    parser.add_argument("--maxlines", dest="maxlines", help="The maximum number of lines that the AI will try to generate per message. Will always generate random amount up to this value, which defaults to 1.",
                        default=1)
    parser.add_argument("--train", dest="train", action="store_true",
                        help="Trains the model on a file named dataset.txt. Only use this if you have a good NVIDIA GPU. Overwrites existing trained_model folder. Currently untested!")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.test:
        ai = ChatAI(args.maxlines)  # see comment on line 33
        print("Type \"exit!!\" to exit.")
        while True:
            inp = input("> ")
            if(inp == "exit!!"):
                return
            print(ai.get_bot_response(message=inp))
    elif args.train:
        from aitextgen import aitextgen #lazily import aitextgen. idk if this matters, but i thought it might speed up start times for when you're not training the AI as opposed to having this at the top
        ai = aitextgen(to_gpu=True)
        ai.train("dataset.txt",
                      line_by_line=False,
                      from_cache=False,
                      num_steps=55000, #Takes less than an hour on my RTX 3060. Increase if you want, but remember that training can pick up where it left off after this finishes.
                      generate_every=1000,
                      save_every=1000,
                      learning_rate=1e-3,
                      fp16=True, #this setting improves memory efficiency, disable if it causes issues
                      batch_size=2,
                      )
    else:
        # probably a cleaner way to do this than to pass the maxlines param all the way through? submit PR if you know
        client = ChatBot(args.maxlines)
        client.set_response_chance(args.response_chance)
        if args.token is None:
            raise Exception(
                "You are trying to launch the bot but have not included your discord bot's token with --token. Please include this and try again.")
        client.run(args.token)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the main.py that starts and runs the other auxiliary scripts.

Comment: Hey welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add the code that your running?

Comment: Yes! I just added it, my apologies.

Comment: Okay so I just learned about inheritance and it seems like the issue is because you are not properly inheriting the attributes of the `Client` class. Try commenting out the line with `super().__init__()` and tell me what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're inheriting from `discord.Client` and never passing the `intents` to the parent class. Additionally, you're then creating a `discord.Bot` within your `discord.Client` subclass? You might as well inherit from `discord.Bot` directly.

```py
class ChatBot(discord.Bot):
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    def __init__(self, maxlines) -> None:
        self.model_name = "355M"  # Overwrite with set_model_name()
        super().__init__(intents=self.intents, command_prefix='.')
        self.maxlines = maxlines
```

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py#L10).

Answer (score -1):

##### Solution

You'll need to pass in a value for the `intents` keyword-only argument: `super().__init__(intents=self.intents)` or `super().__init__(intents=ChatBot.intents)`.

- Note: I'm not sure if the value for the keyword-only argument (i.e.
  `intents`) is supposed to be the class variable `intents` (i.e.
  `discord.Intents.all()`). But
  [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Client)
  says, that the keyword-only argument, `intents`, is "The intents that
  you want to enable for the session. This is a way of disabling and
  enabling certain gateway events from triggering and being sent."

##### Explanation for the TypeError

You received a TypeError because `super()` returns an instance of the inherited class (i.e. `Client`) and the constructor in the `Client` class initializes the keyword-only attribute, `intents`. Thus, `super().__init__()` expected to receive the required attributes of the inherited class.

This [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSl87lqOXDE) helped me better understand what was going on.